# import model from rhapsody to papyrus

Tags: import, papyrus, rhapsody

I would like to import the rhapsody models in papyrus (eclipse).
it is possible make an import in payarus in order to keep the same information?
- Use cases
- Diagrams of sequences
- classes

Furthermore. I know rhapsody has dependencies with a OXF library, when I will make the migration in papyrus'll have to specify this addiction?
thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be able to export the rhapsody project to XMI and use that to create a similar Papyrus project. You will most likely lose any diagrams and will have some weird Rhapsody stereotypes but it kinda works.

Start by creating a new Papyrus project. Close that project and open up the *.uml file in the project directory. Replace the text with the XML created from the Rhapsody project. Save. Reopen the project in Papyrus.

I tested this on a small rhapsody project. It seemed to get all the relationships and classes correct but completely messed up all the diagrams.

To answer your second question, those dependecies are for the actual code that Rhapsody generates from your UML model. So the actual model does not depend on those libraries. If you were hoping to also carry over your code from the Rhapsody model you may be out of luck.